# If $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{[(n-1)/2]}(-1)^k\ _nC_{2k+1}\ x^k$, find $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ such that $P_{n+2}(x)=A(x)P_{n+1}(x)+B(x)P_n(x)$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, problem-solving

A high school math problem:

> For $n \in N$ (the natural number set), let us define the polynomial $P_n(x)$ as follows:
>
> $$P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{[(n-1)/2]}(-1)^k \ {}_nC_{2k+1} \ x^k$$
>
> where $[(n-1)/2]$ represents the greatest integer that does not exceed $(n-1)/2$.
>
> Find the expressions for the polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ such that for all $n \in N$
>
> $$P_{n+2}(x) = A(x)P_{n+1}(x) + B(x)P_n(x)$$

Someone has said it should start from rearranging the formula and stating that

$$P_n(x) = \frac{(1+i \sqrt{x})^n - (1-i \sqrt{x})^n }{2i\sqrt{x}}$$

And from here I am able to do the rest of the steps. But I do not see intuitively how I can reach this expression.

Comment: *"I've got some specific questions but will not present for now because I want to see the ways with which you come up with new ideas."* ... That's not how this works. Withholding what you know raises the possibility that people will waste their valuable time duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand. That is inconsiderate to those you are asking for help.

Comment: @Blue Made changes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing more than Markus Scheuer did, but simply organized a bit differently. Note that $\binom{n}{2k+1}=0$ if $2k+1\gt n$.
$$
P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k+1}x^k
$$
Substitute $x\mapsto-x$
$$
P_n(-x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{2k+1}x^k
$$
Substitute $x\mapsto x^2$, then multiply by $x$ and recognize that the sum is the odd part of $(1+x)^n$. The odd part of a function is $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2$.
$$
\begin{align}
xP_n\!\left(-x^2\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}\\
&=\frac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}2
\end{align}
$$
Divide by $x$ and substitute $x\mapsto i\sqrt{x}$
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{(1+i\sqrt{x})^n-(1-i\sqrt{x})^n}{2i\sqrt{x}}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{P_n(x)}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k+1}x^k}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}i^{2k}\binom{n}{2k+1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{2k}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{i\sqrt{x}}{i\sqrt{x}}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}i^{2k}\binom{n}{2k+1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^{2k}\\
&=\frac{1}{i\sqrt{x}}\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k+1}\left(i\sqrt{x}\right)^{2k+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{x}}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(i\sqrt{x}\right)^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(i\sqrt{x}\right)^{k}\right]\tag{3}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{x}}\left[\left(1+i\sqrt{x}\right)^n-\left(1-i\sqrt{x}\right)^n\right]}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use for convenient notation $\binom{n}{k}:=_nC_{k}$.
- In (2) we use the identities $i^2=-1$ and $x=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2$.
- In (3) we represent the terms with odd index $2k+1$ as sum of all terms minus the terms with even index $2k$. Note, we have to divide by $2$ since we add the odd terms twice.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem twice.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I didn't understand how each line leads to the corresponding results.. And it seems too ingenious to come up with that idea. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @curious: I've added some intermediate steps.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I saw it just now.